# How to calculate moving avg over time?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data of sensors coming anytime. I want to group them by sensors and calculate the average over X minutes or hours. I tried to do my own but did not work. You can check the fiddle [here][1].

In short, I have to show sensors wise moving average data against X minutes or hours.
[1]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e3101/14

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the output you want?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Data is keep coming from sensors, if the time duration is given, for example, 3 minutes of 10 minutes, it creates a window of that X Minutes of records and average them. For example data cam,e at 11:25, 11:26,11:27,11:28, 11:29 and 11:30, it is 5 minutes, whatever the average became for last 5 minutes it should show it.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the expected output based on your sample data (as formatted text, no screen shots please)

Comment: [Minimal, complete sample code](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and data should be included in the [question itself](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/90527). Note that adding a link to a live example *in addition* to having code in the question is welcomed, but it shouldn't take its place.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear to me what output you are after, but maybe you are looking for a `range` condition for the window function:

```
select r.sensor_id,
       r.reading,
       r."timestamp",
       AVG(r.reading) OVER (partition by r.sensor_id 
                            ORDER BY r."timestamp" 
                            range between interval '5 minute' PRECEDING 
                                      AND CURRENT ROW) as avg_reading
from sensor_readings r 
order by r.sensor_id, r."timestamp"
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=193ac1128c50b1d7bb3d33dbe6b2463b)

Comment: Didn't know window functions were so powerful.

Comment: Can you explain this?  I guess `PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW` is checking current and last row only and averaging out it but how is it applying `5 minute` here? Pls explain this

Comment: Not it operates on an interval, not on the number of rows. That's the difference between `rows between` and `range between`. See [here](https://modern-sql.com/blog/2019-02/postgresql-11#over) for an introduction

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so is it averaging out based on rows appear in last 5 minutes?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think this answer of yours doing what I am looking for but it is too complex for me to understand

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13820529/275002

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the group by clause, you need the partition clause. Try if this works.

```
Select sensor_id, 
       reading, 
       date_trunc('hour', "timestamp") AS sensor_reading_hour,
       AVG(reading) OVER(PARTITION BY sensor_id ORDER BY date_trunc('hour', "timestamp")) as avg_reading
from sensor_readings
```

Comment: But I need to average over time like 5 minutes/hour etc, how do I do it